# NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed still caching for NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, http, caching, nsurlrequest

I am working on an iPhone app project now which implements some connections using `NSURLRequests` using `cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed` (I am using ios 7).

But it seems like the responses are still cached and I get old responses for the same URL call. In spite of having the cache policy as `"cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed".`

Why is it still caching the responses? Is the issue still present in the latest release?

Comment: +Piyali your questions are generaly badly tagged. Often it is reasonable to at least add the language as tag so it can easily be found by people dealing with the involved technology.

Answer (score 3):

The correct enum for the cache Policy iOS7 is as described below:

```
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL
cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
```

If you are over 3G, some provider use caching even if you disable it in your `NSMutableURLRequest`, so if the cache policy doesn't work then set the http header field cache-control to no-cache.

```
[request setValue:@"no-cache" forHTTPHeaderField:@"cache-control"];
```

Here the enum list check your header NSURLRequest.h for the correct up to date enum :)

```
enum
{
    NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy = 0,

    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData = 1,
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData = 4, // Unimplemented
    NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData,

    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad = 2,
    NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad = 3,

    NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData = 5, // Unimplemented
};
 typedef NSUInteger NSURLRequestCachePolicy;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer for a non cached request should be `NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:downloadURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:60];` since NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData it's unimplemented.

From https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlrequestcachepolicy/nsurlrequestreloadignoringlocalcachedata?language=objc